# How to implement extended apply method? Java

Tags: java

My question has to do with implementing the FlatApply class that I have created previously into this class called FilteringFlatApplyFunction. I cannot seem to implement the apply correctly because the static class continues to tell me it needs to be abstract and the @Override is not working the way it is supposed to. The end goal I am looking for is a way to use inheritance to borrow most of the functionality from the FlatApply class and implement the filter class. I have tried many different things but still can't get it, the predicate "pred" checks if the given predicate is true and if so, indicates to return the element, I thought that would implement FlatApply,I have been getting this error what seems like forever now. Thanks

Error:

FilteringFlatApplyFunction is not abstract and does not override abstract method apply(T) in FlatApplyFunction
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class FilteringFlatApplyFunction

```
package iterators;


import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import iterators.Apply;

// Iterator that uses a Predicate to filter out elements from the input
public class Filter<T> extends FlatApply<T,T> {   
        public Filter(Predicate<T> p, Iterator<T> input) {             
            super(new FilteringFlatApplyFunction<T>(p),input);


 }

// uses a Predicate to decide whether the input element is output or not

private static class FilteringFlatApplyFunction<T> implements FlatApplyFunction<T,T> {                       
        private final Predicate pred;        

        public FilteringFlatApplyFunction(Predicate<T> p) {                              
            this.pred = p; 

        }            
        @Override
        public T apply(Iterator T) {
            T result = null;
            if((!T.hasNext())) throw new IllegalStateException();
                if (pred.check(T.next()) == true){
                    result = (T) T.next();  
                    }                 
                else{
                    return (T) T; 
                }

    }
```

Here is the FlatApply

```
package iterators;


import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;


public class FlatApply<InT,OutT> implements Iterator<OutT> {  

    private final Iterator<InT> input;

    private final FlatApplyFunction<InT,OutT> f;

    private final Queue<OutT> q;



        public FlatApply(FlatApplyFunction<InT,OutT> f, Iterator<InT> input) {                
                this.input = input;
                this.f = f;
                this.q = new LinkedList<OutT>();         
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
                if (!q.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    while(q.isEmpty() && input.hasNext()) {
                        List<OutT> result = f.apply(input.next());
                        q.addAll(result);
                    }
                    if(q.isEmpty()) return false;
                    else return true;
                }
            }
            @Override
    public OutT next() {

                if((!hasNext())) throw new IllegalStateException();
                return q.poll();
                }


            }
```

Here is the FlatApplyFunction

```
package iterators;


import java.util.List;


public interface FlatApplyFunction<InT, OutT> {
        public List<OutT> apply(InT x);
}
```

Here is the apply class

```
package iterators;


import java.util.Iterator;

public class Apply<InT,OutT> implements Iterator<OutT> {
    // The function that will be applied to each input element to make an       output element
    private final ApplyFunction<InT,OutT> f;

    // The Iterator that this Apply object will get its input from
    private final Iterator<InT> input;      

    public Apply(ApplyFunction<InT, OutT> f, Iterator<InT> input) {
                this.input = input;
                this.f = f;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
                return input.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public OutT next() {
                if((!hasNext())) throw new IllegalStateException();
                OutT result = f.apply(input.next());                   
                return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show `FlatApply` and `FlatApplyFunction`.

Comment: It is now updated to show both

Comment: @Jeremy I also added the apply

Answer (score 1):

The `FlatApplyFunction` interface says this:

```
public List<OutT> apply(InT x);
```

But the `FilteringFlatApplyFunction` implementation of that interface says this:

```
public T apply(Iterator T) {
```

The interface requires a `List` to be returned, by you're just returning `T`. Also, the parameter is required to be a `T`, but you have it as an `Iterator`.

Make those match, and this compiler error should go away.

Comment: Thank You that worked. However doesn't that then disable me to use hasNext() and next() in the implementation

Comment: not fully but wouldn't I need to use next in order to check the predicate

Comment: Then change the interface to except an `Iterator<T>` rather than a `T`.

Comment: I need to keep the interface as it is

Comment: Perhaps you don't need an Iterator passed in to FilteringFlatApplyFunction. Maybe you just need to check if the `T` passes the predicate or not?